# XMLEventReader not found in JAXB 2.2.7

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb

My environment is running JAVA 1.5 and put JAXB 2.2.7 into my POM file in this manner.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

However, when I build my jar file, I encounter this error.

> cannot access javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader file
>   javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.class not found

When I look into jaxb-api.jar, XMLEventReader is not there. But I am not sure why it is not. Shouldn't it be included? When I tried to use http://www.findjar.com/ to locate XMLEventReader, I realised it is in jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar.

Was it removed in the later version?

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. The problem was with my Eclipse environment setup. The JRE System Library writes J2SE 1.5 but it was linked to my JDK1.6 directory. Therefore, there was no issue in my local environment building. However, when I moved it to my staging environment, the error occurs. I have no added StAX into my POM and it works fine. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XMLEventReader` is from StAX (JSR-173) and not JAXB (JSR-222).  You will need to include the StAX APIs in your pom file.  Both the StAX and JAXB APIs are included in Java SE 6 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to include stAX APIs in your POM file.This is readily available from Java SE7